# why sum(x/y)/n is not equal to sum(x)/sum(y) where x and y are vector of n positive integers?

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

Example:

[image]

Why sum(x)/sum(y) is not equivalent (equal) to sum(x/y)/n???

Comment: Suppose one of the y values was 0; what would you expect sum(x/y)/n to be?

Comment: y value is positive integer and will not be zero

Comment: Irrelevant. The fact that one of them *could* be 0 should show that your conjecture is false.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about arithmetic and not about programming.

Comment: The answer gives a counter example to show they are not equal (but you knew that) to answer why "philosophically" (as you put it) they are not equal, in sum(x)/sum(y) every y value contributes to the divisor of every x value, in sum(x/y) they are paired up. The second y does not divide the first x. if any one of the y values is huge, sum(x)/sum(y) gets small, but sum(x/y) just ends up with one small term.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have two values of x (3 and 6) and 2 values of y (5 and 11). Now sum(x)=9 and sum(y)=16, dividing them, we get 0.5625. Then we find sum(x/y). That would be (3/5)+(6/11)=0.6+0.5454= 1.1454. Dividing by n (2), we get the answer 0.57. So you see, sum(x)/sum(y) and sum(x/y)/n are two essentially very different things.

They might produce the same answer in some cases e.g. when y values are (5 and 10) but not always.

Comment: Philosophically these two values need to be equivalent right? say we are calculating average of accuracy where x is predicted true and y is total predicted, then if we calculate the average accuracy on the either way, the values should be equivalent? or I am thinking somehow wrong?

Comment: No, that is what i am trying to explain, they are not equivalent. Continuing with my example. Sum(x)/sum(y) can be written as (3+6)/(5+11). Whereas sum(x/y)/n will be (3/5 + 6/11)(1/2). Do the calculation and you will find that they won't be the same

Comment: If the answer solved your query, please mark it as the solution.